# WPF Listbox with textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a listbox with a textbox

The textbox is defined in a datatemplate that ends like this

```
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="Note"></TextBlock>
    <TextBox Height="Auto" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" 
        Text="{Binding PartData.Note}" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" >
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

I want the textbox to expand when the user enters multiple rows but it doesnt. The rowdefintion height is set to `*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried your sample with this code, and it works (use Shift-Enter to start a new row inside TextBox)

```
<Window x:Class="TextBoxWrap.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Height="140" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Note"/>
                        <TextBox Margin ="10, 0,0,0" Height="Auto" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Count}" 
                            AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>       
      </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Found it , i had added a initital size on the row and then its locked. I changed it and added inital size on the textbox instead and then it works

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
```

to TextBox so it takes all available space.

Comment: No , didnt work textbox is still fixed and does not expand with the text